# Type lost when exporting object on baseDir import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a file named `constants.ts` which contains constants related to my React TypeScript application.

The file looks like this:

```js
// The error for when errors are bad.
const BAD_ERROR_ERROR = "Something happened that shouldn't have. Please contact an admin";

const Constants = {
    APIResponses: {
        accounts: {
            login: {
                account_not_verified: {
                    message: "You need to verify your email",
                    problemFields: ["email"]
                },
                bad_login: {
                    message: "Your email or password is incorrect",
                    problemFields: ["email", "password"]
                },
                default: {
                    message: BAD_ERROR_ERROR,
                    problemFields: ["email", "passwords"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

export default Constants;
```

I then import it in a TSX file like this:

```js
import Constants from "constants";
```

and reference a key like this:

```js
        const { status } = json;
        const resp = Constants.APIResponses.accounts.login[status.message];
```

However, when I attempt to use it, I get this error:

```js
Property 'APIResponses' does not exist on type 'typeof import("constants")'.  TS2339

    69 | 
    70 |         const { status } = json;
  > 71 |         const resp = Constants.APIResponses.accounts.login[status.message];
```

This error **only occurs** when importing it from my baseDir as `"constants"`, when importing as `../../constants`, it works fine. (That's the work around I'm going with right now)

Here's the things I've tried that haven't worked:

- Explicitly defining a type for Constants in constants.ts
- Renaming it to constants.js
- Casting the type on the default export
- Not exporting it as default

Here's the hacky fixes I found that work, but are hacky and undesirable:

- Importing it relatively (`../../constants`) **(current)**
- Casting it to an any type (`(Constants as any).APIResponses...`)

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The fact that it's working with a relative import tells me the issue is likely in your `tsconfig.json` configuration. Can you add your TypeScript configuration to the question?

Comment: @AndrewHill Good point - done.

Comment: Change your include to `"include": ["src/**/*"]` and your baseUrl to `"baseUrl": "src"`. Remove your `rootDir` as that is only used to control the output directory with the `outDir` flag.

Comment: Also worth checking (but rather unlikely) is if it works with `"strict": false`. If it does then that means one of the strict flags are interfering with your imports. For a list of strict flags that are switched on when using strict, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: @AndrewHill Tried everything (including `strict: false`), and am still where I was.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Best of luck figuring this one out!